# Get Notification about new/changed/deleted contacts in Android when App is not running

Tags: android, notifications, contacts, observers

it there a way to get noticed if a new or changed contact is made in Android? I want to get notified when the app starts, if there are any changes. Using a ContentObserver seems to me, that the app must run it in a activity. Or do i have to load all contacts every time from my DB and i am only able to recognize contact changed while my app runs and has an implemented ContentObserver?

Answer (score 0):

> i am only able to recognize contact changed while my app runs and has an implemented ContentObserver?

Correct, at least through Android 6.0.

The N Developer Preview has an enhanced `JobScheduler` that implements a `ContentObserver` for you, invoking your `JobService` when a change is detected. Unless there are problems, we can expect that enhanced `JobScheduler` to ship in the next release of Android, and you can opt into using it on newer Android devices.

Comment: Is there a way to use a broadcastreceiver with an service? I searched for a intent from the system, but didn't found something, which fits to a changed contact?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, what i did now is: Using a background service and build up an ContentObservice in the onCreate() function. Finally declaring it in the manifest. It will of course not work if the App is totally closed but if it is in background. Thats enough for me. It detects changes to the contacts. Are there any disadvantages in using this approach?

This is the service:

```
public class ContactsChangeService extends IntentService {
/**
 * An IntentService must always have a constructor that calls the super constructor. The
 * string supplied to the super constructor is used to give a name to the IntentService's
 * background thread.
 */
public ContactsChangeService() {

    super("ContactsChangeReceiver");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //if created make an Observer
    ContactsChangeObserver contentObserver = new ContactsChangeObserver();
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "[" + Constants.CONTACTS_OBSERVER_SERVICE + "] " + "started");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    // Gets data from the incoming Intent
    String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
    //...



    // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString
    //...
}
```

}

This is the Observer:

```
public class ContactsChangeObserver extends ContentObserver{

    public ContactsChangeObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "[" + Constants.CONTACTS_OBSERVER_SERVICE + "] " + "Change in Contacts detected");
    }
```

}

And this is the manifest entry:

```
        <service
        android:name=".service.ContactsChangeService"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
```